# NodeJs receiving callback object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

I am developing authentication module for my app. Whenever username and password is posted to '/admin/login' Api it invokes Auth controller's login function.
Further I am using mongoose model to query from MongoDb and return the found object to a variable.

auth.controller.js

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var User = require('../models/user.model.js');
var secret = require('../config.js').jwt_secret;
var auth = {
login : function (req, res) {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    if (username === '' || password === '') {
        res.status(401).json({message : 'Invalid Credentials'});
        return;
    }

    var dbUserObj = auth.validate(username, password); // receives the User object returned from callback

        console.log(dbUserObj); //displays 'undefined'

    if (!dbUserObj) {

        res.status(401).json({message : 'Invalid Username or Password'});
        return;
    }

    if (dbUserObj) {
        console.log('user found');
        res.json(genToken(dbUserObj));
    }
},

validate : function (user, pass) {
      User.findOne({username : user}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
        if (user==null) {
            console.log('no user found');
            return;
        } else {

            bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password, function (err,result) {
             if (result == true) {
                return user;
             }
         });
        }

      });
}
 }


function genToken (user) {
  var expires = expiresIn(7);
  var token = jwt.encode({exp : expires},secret);
  return {
    token : token,
    exp : expires,
    user: user
  }
}

function expiresIn (t) {
var dateObj = new Date();
return dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays); 
}

 module.exports = auth;
```

The dbUserobject variable receives the User object returned by the validate function. But if I log this variable it shows 'undefined'
I know there is callback issue that the next lines of code runs and after callback returns the object dbUserObject variable is initialized and it always send the response 'Invalid username or password' because dbUserObject becomes undefined.
I tried several stuff but couldn't sort out.

How can I make this to work like it first receives the DbUserObj and then decides whether to send invalid response or generate Json Web token.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is problem of **Sync** and **Async** functions as your `auth.validate` behave as async not wait for result due to which user object getting undefined you can solve this by using `Promise` try this

```
var auth = {
login : function (req, res) {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    if (username === '' || password === '') {
        res.status(401).json({message : 'Invalid Credentials'});
        return;
    }

        auth.validate(username, password)
        .then(function(dbUserObj) { // `validate` returns a promise
        console.log(dbUserObj); // Log the value once it is resolved
                if (!dbUserObj) {

                    res.status(401).json({message : 'Invalid Username or Password'});
                    return;
                }

                if (dbUserObj) {
                    console.log('user found');
                    res.json(genToken(dbUserObj));
                }

        console.log(dbUserObj); //displays 'undefined'

        }).catch(function(v) {
        // Or do something else if it is rejected 
        // (it would not happen in this example, since `reject` is not called).
        });





},

validate : function (user, pass) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

           User.findOne({username : user}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return;
            }
            if (user==null) {
                console.log('no user found');
                return;
            } else {

                bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password, function (err,result) {
                 if (result == true) {
                    return user;
                 }
             });
            }

          });
        // Only `delay` is able to resolve or reject the promise
        setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(user); // After 3 seconds, resolve the promise with user
        }, 3000);
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: Wasiq, thank you for this. Now I got the whole idea but could you please elaborate about the delay? Why delay is required? Would I get the User without delay? If I have to use delay why shouldn't I use callback with delay?

Comment: as `callback` is same as `promise` but promise are more manageable code.you can use without delay as well. I suggest you to use `bluebird` promise in your node and also dont use this two function in `auth` method make separate function or like `service` for best practises

Comment: How about Promise.js library? I have checked blue bird it has some compatibility issues.

Comment: `bluebird` is mature and stable package and used in most production environment

Comment: @SHAHRUKHSHAHID if you understand a phenomena or idea select and upvote an answer so it should be closed